# Rails respond_to redirect all requests except X mime-type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is the typical respond_to block im using in my controller

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
  end
```

I want to restrict all mime-types except html(lets say).
Couldn't come up with a solution, how is this possible? This block does nothing if the request is json, this is OK but what I want is to redirect any requests that are not html.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `format` object yielded by `respond_to` has all of the usual mime types (html, js, xml, etc), and it also has a catch-all mime type `any` that will handle everything else. So, in this case:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.any { redirect_to :foo }
end
```

will use default rendering for html, and will redirect for everything else. See the docs for (a tiny bit) more information: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to

Comment: yes tried that format.any before, but at the case above, requests with html mime types are also being redirected to foo, so this doesn't resolve it..

Comment: They should be handled in order, so `format.html` should win over `format.any`. If you had them in the right order, and still were having issues, I'd check for bugs, or add a block to `format.html` and `format.any` to see if you can break in with a debugger and identify why it isn't doing what you expect

Comment: adding some dummy code to format.html resolved it! format.html {
        puts "blabla"
      } don't know why this doesn't work without a code block. anyway thanks for your help :-)